# Getting Screen-On Time in Android by API?

Tags: java, android, screen

is there a way to get the Screen-On Time of an Android Phone by an Application? Better Battery Stats get the Time but i don't know how? Is there an API?

Comment: Please define "Screen-On Time".

Comment: Do you mean "Screen-On Timeout", e.i. when the screen is going to turn off because user inactivity or press the power on button?

Comment: screen on time means the time in Battery->Screen->Time on